# unable to locate element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Below is my code to locate an element.

```
WebElement clickNextButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Export')]"));
         clickNextButton.click();
```

I want to locate a button,among multiple buttons with same name and with same CSS code as below:

```
<button ng-disabled="tx.QA_Status != 'VERIFIED'" class="btn btn-primary gray btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exportTransactionModal" ng-click="resetModal('exportTransactionModal');exportTransaction(tx.head,tx.transactionId);">
                                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>&nbsp;Export
                            </button>


<button ng-disabled="tx.QA_Status != 'VERIFIED'" class="btn btn-primary gray btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exportTransactionModal" ng-click="resetModal('exportTransactionModal');exportTransaction(tx.head,tx.transactionId);">
                                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>&nbsp;Export
                            </button>
```

I am unable to locate because transaction is done using AngularJS. and `exportTransaction` method is called in JS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
By.xpath("(//button[@class='btn btn-primary gray btn-xs'])[1]");
```

The above xpath will locate the first match.

Comment: when i search for xpath it shows  "/html/body/div[2]/div[7]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/button[1]"

Comment: You have used absolute xpath.Instead of using absolute xpath ,start using relative xpath because when there is a change in the DOM ,absolute xpath will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
$$('.btn.btn-primary.gray.btn-xs').first();
```

if the `Export` button is first element

Or

```
$$('.btn.btn-primary.gray.btn-xs')[0] //for the first element with the class.
```

Or

```
$$('.btn.btn-primary.gray.btn-xs').get(index).element(by.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Export')]"))
```

Comment: /* WebElement container = button.findElement(By.xpath("current()/ancestor-or-self::button[1][contains(@class, 'btn.btn-primary.gray.btn-xs')]") );
   container.click();*/
   
   
  /*driver.manage().window().maximize();
   WebDriverWait wait5 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
   WebElement button3 = wait5.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("btn.btn-primary.gray.btn-xs[text()='Export'][0]")));
   button3.click();*/

Comment: i iused all above formats.